# how to switch domain of two wordpress site with each other

Tags: wordpress

I have two wordpress site on same server with different domain name.
[here is first one](http://naturesmoringa.com/)

[here is the second one](http://naturalmoringa.com/)

My client is saying that he want to switch the domain name for both site with each other that is first domain will work on second one and second on the first one.

how to do this any idea or help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: wordpress embeds hostnames pervasively throughout the database in permalinks and whatnot. You'll have to dump the database, mangle each name as appropriate in the dump, and reload.

Answer (score 0):

The free way:

1. Download each site to separate folders on your hard drive.
2. Make a database backup of each site with phpmyadmin
3. Delete both websites via ftp
4. Clear out both databases
5. Upload site 1 to site 2's former location and vice versa.
6. Load up phpmyadmin and restore database 1 to database 2 and vice versa.
7. In each database, open up the wp_options table and change `siteurl` and `home` to reflect the new domain name
8. Using phpmyadmin's search function, search for the old url in all tables, and manually update them if necessary.

The paid way:

Use ManageWP or BackupBuddy to assist in automating the above. With either tool you can make a full backup and then restore to a different server, and they automate the domain name change.